# how can I remove blank spot after skewY in html?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to combine two pictures in HTML, but I am seeing the blank spot after using skewY in CSS. How can i make bottom image and white spot to combine it to fit in the design view?

Below is HTML. I am adding image 1 into `<div class="header__bg">` and image 2 into `<section class="main_image">.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HTMLPage2.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header__bg"></div>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="main_image">
    <h1>Section Content</h1>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is CSS. I am trying to code to add 2 images make shape i want. I would like to see blank part to be part of bottom image.

```
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header__bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("GettyImages2.jpg");
    transform: skewY(-6deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
section.main_image {
    background-image: url("GettyImages1.jpg");
}


h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0;
    font: 44px "Arial";
    text-align: left;
    margin: 35px;
}

header h1 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}
```

I see white section between images and I would like white section to be part of bottom image. Is there any ways to do this?

Comment: Since we got 2 different tag element, I think you can achieve that with `margin-top: some negative value` to pull your second image to the top. But if you could provide us some image or something about what you expected to do, we can help you much better!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mNfgNq4 This is the output that I am trying to get now

Comment: Well, you can check my answer, and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to get what you wanted.

**Note:** I just used two different random image samples from the internet for better illustration.

- **Margin with negative values:**

First of all, you can try `margin-top: some negative values;` (in my example I just used *-77px*) and adding `z-index: 1;` to your upper image and also `header h1` to ensure that it will always remain at top of the lower image. (There is no necessity for `z-index` in this approach.)

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header__bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://www.cranfield.ac.uk/~/media/images-for-new-website/rio/ktp/clear-water-drops-pexels-400x400.ashx?h=400&w=400&la=en&hash=18C2E8C4D228436DBA9414C59FBDFF01268A6681");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: skewY(-6deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    z-index: 1;
}
section.main_image {
    background-image: url("https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a704f043-a0fb-4652-b8ee-6bc362dae5a9/d5j1z44-0c21f546-39eb-48f9-8230-0b4500c7b88f.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2E3MDRmMDQzLWEwZmItNDY1Mi1iOGVlLTZiYzM2MmRhZTVhOVwvZDVqMXo0NC0wYzIxZjU0Ni0zOWViLTQ4ZjktODIzMC0wYjQ1MDBjN2I4OGYuanBnIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.O_Xy26vERxse28DI8z2gwy-z0M9aBlGMXJSOwbi8_nM");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: -77px;
}


h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0;
    font: 44px "Arial";
    text-align: left;
    margin: 35px;
}

header h1 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HTMLPage2.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header__bg"></div>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="main_image">
    <h1>Section Content</h1>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

- **Transform with translateY:**
  Like the last one, you can add `transform: translateY(some negative value);` to your lower image to pull it up and `z-index: 1;` to your higher image. (`z-index` is necessary for this approach).

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header__bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://www.cranfield.ac.uk/~/media/images-for-new-website/rio/ktp/clear-water-drops-pexels-400x400.ashx?h=400&w=400&la=en&hash=18C2E8C4D228436DBA9414C59FBDFF01268A6681");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: skewY(-6deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    z-index: 1;
}
section.main_image {
    background-image: url("https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a704f043-a0fb-4652-b8ee-6bc362dae5a9/d5j1z44-0c21f546-39eb-48f9-8230-0b4500c7b88f.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2E3MDRmMDQzLWEwZmItNDY1Mi1iOGVlLTZiYzM2MmRhZTVhOVwvZDVqMXo0NC0wYzIxZjU0Ni0zOWViLTQ4ZjktODIzMC0wYjQ1MDBjN2I4OGYuanBnIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.O_Xy26vERxse28DI8z2gwy-z0M9aBlGMXJSOwbi8_nM");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: translateY(-77px)
}


h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0;
    font: 44px "Arial";
    text-align: left;
    margin: 35px;
}

header h1 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HTMLPage2.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header__bg"></div>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="main_image">
    <h1>Section Content</h1>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

- **Giving transform skew to both images:**
  The last two approaches got a little con where the upper dimension of the lower image get behind the higher image to avoid that we can go into another approach, it is not so clean and tidy but it will do the work for us. For this cause, I modified your code a bit and you can see the results in the code snippet below:

```css
body > div {
  height: 560px;
}

body > div,
header,
section {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header,
section {
  height: 300px;
}

.header__bg,
.main_image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.header__bg {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("https://www.cranfield.ac.uk/~/media/images-for-new-website/rio/ktp/clear-water-drops-pexels-400x400.ashx?h=400&w=400&la=en&hash=18C2E8C4D228436DBA9414C59FBDFF01268A6681");
    z-index: 1;
}

section.main_image {
    background-image: url("https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a704f043-a0fb-4652-b8ee-6bc362dae5a9/d5j1z44-0c21f546-39eb-48f9-8230-0b4500c7b88f.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2E3MDRmMDQzLWEwZmItNDY1Mi1iOGVlLTZiYzM2MmRhZTVhOVwvZDVqMXo0NC0wYzIxZjU0Ni0zOWViLTQ4ZjktODIzMC0wYjQ1MDBjN2I4OGYuanBnIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.O_Xy26vERxse28DI8z2gwy-z0M9aBlGMXJSOwbi8_nM");
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0;
    font: 44px "Arial";
    text-align: left;
    margin: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
}

header h1 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

section > h1 {
  transform: skewY(6deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HTMLPage2.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <header>
        <div class="header__bg"></div>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="main_image">
      <h1>Section Content</h1>
    </section>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot!